# List columns in temp / volatile table in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

How can I list the columns in a volatile table in Teradata? The bottom part works if it's a real table, but not volatile.

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE temptemp (
  A integer
  )
  ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
  
SELECT  
ColumnName
FROM    DBC.ColumnsV
WHERE
TableName = 'temptemp';
```

Comment: There's no metadata stored in DBC for Volatile Tables, try `help table temptemp` or `show table temptemp`